# Get Gridview cell data using javascript with paging

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a gridview, in which I am able to get data as per page. But I want to get all pages data.

```
for(i=0; i<grdview.clientid; i++)
{   
    var checkboxCell = grid.rows[i].cells[8];
}
```

For using it. Its only get cuurent page data. How can I get all pages data.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As par your question we are not able to get all page data by javascript. Reason behind that javascript only reads data that present or binded at current time since no postback occur that get data and bind to page. 
You only access the current page data.

For this you can get data by javascript and do paging by javacript using jquery ajax.